# How to structure Point Light Sources?

Tags: graphics, lighting

I am using Java to write a very primitive 3D graphics engine based on The Black Art of 3D Game Programming from 1995. I have gotten to the point where I can draw single color polygons to the screen and move the camera around the "scene". I even have a Z buffer that handles translucent objects properly by sorting those pixels by Z, as long as I don't show too many translucent pixels at once. I am at the point where I want to add lighting. I want to keep it simple, and ambient light seems simple enough, directional light should be fairly simple too. But I really want point lighting with the ability to move the light source around and cast very primitive shadows ( mostly I don't want light shining through walls ).

My problem is that I don't know the best way to approach this. I imagine a point light source casting rays at regular angles, and if these rays intersect a polygon it will light that polygon and stop moving forward. However when I think about a scene with multiple light sources and multiple polygons with all those rays I imagine it will get very slow. I also don't know how to handle a case where a polygon is far enough away from a light source that if falls in between two rays. I would give each light source a maximum distance, and if I gave it enough rays, then there should be no point within that distance that any two rays are too far apart to miss a polygon, but that only increases my problem with the number of calculations to perform.

My question to you is: Is there some trick to point light sources to speed them up or just to organize it better? I'm afraid I'll just get a nightmare of nested for loops. I can't use openGL or Direct3D or any other cheats because I want to write my own.

If you want to see my results so far, here is a youtube video. I have already fixed the bad camera rotation. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_XYj113Le58&feature=plcp

Answer (score 1):

Lighting for real time  3d applications is (or rather - has in the past generally been) done by very simple approximations - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shading. Shadows are expensive - and have generally in rasterizing 3d engines been accomplished via [shadow maps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_mapping) & [Shadow Volumes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_volume). Point lights make shadows even more expensive.

Dynamic real time light sources have only recently become a common feature in games - simply because they place such a heavy burden on the rendering system.  And these games leverage dedicated graphics cards. So I think you may struggle to get good performance out of your engine if you decide to include dynamic - shadow casting - point lights.

Today it is commonplace for lighting to be applied in two ways:

1. Traditionally this has been "forward rendering".  In this method, for every vertex (if you are doing the lighting per vertex) or fragment (if you are doing it per-pixel) you would calculate the contribution of each light source.
2. More recently, "deferred" lighting has become popular, wherein the geometry and extra data like normals & colour info are all rendered to intermediate buffers - which is then used to calculate lighting contributions.  This way, the lighting calculations are not dependent on the geometry count.  It does however, have a lot of other overhead.

There are a lot of options.  Implementing anything much more complex than some the basic models that have been used by dedicated graphics cards over the past couple of years is going to be challenging, however!

My suggestion would be to start out with something simple - basic lighting without shadows.  From there you can extend and optimize.

---

What are you doing the ray-triangle intersection test for? Are you trying to light only triangles which the light would reach? Ray-triangle
intersections for every light with every poly is going to be very expensive I think.  For lighting without shadows, typically you would
just iterate through every face (or if you are doing it per vertex, through every vertex) and calculate & add the lighting contribution per light - you would do this just before you start rasterizing as you have to pass through all polys in anycase.

You can calculate the lighting by making use of any illumination model, something very simple like  [Lambertian reflectance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambertian_reflectance) - which shades the surface based upon the dot product of the normal of the surface and the direction vector from the surface to the light. Make sure your vectors are in the same spaces!  This is possibly why you are getting the strange results that you are. If your surface normal is in world space, be sure to calculate the world space light vector.  There are a bunch of advantages for calulating lighting in certain spaces, you can have a look at that later on, for now I suggest you just get the basics up and running.  Also have a look at  [Blinn-phong](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blinn%E2%80%93Phong_shading_model) - this is the shading model graphics cards used for many years.

For lighting with shadows - look into the links I posted. They were developed because realistic lighting is so expensive to calculate.

By the way, LaMothe had a follow up book called Tricks of the 3D Game Programming Gurus-Advanced 3D Graphics and Rasterization.
This takes you through every step of programming a 3d engine.  I am not sure what the black art book covers.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I tried to set up a flat shader using a point light source and a ray-triangle intersection algorithm I found. The sides of my cubes are being rendered in different shades, but the sides parallel to the light rays are brighter than the faces that face the light source, and the faces on the opposite side of my cubes are being lit too. I suspect I didn't do the intersection detection right. I have some advantages in that I only have 320 by 240 pixels, and plan to keep polygon count low, but this is going to be tough. I have forgetten most of my matrix algebra.

Comment: You're gonna have to brush up on your matrix math/Linear algebra, thats what 3d graphics is all about :P I have updated my answer - my reply didn't fit in a comment.

Comment: I wanted to do the intersection tests so that light couldn't pass through walls. I don't want shadows for moving objects or furniture, etc. I figured walls and floors would have fewer polygons to test. I think the lighting model used the black art book was the same as the lambertian model, but I have to double check the formula. For shading I was going to use gourad shading, if not a flat shading. I might have to look at the other book, the black art book uses a lot of tricks based on DOS and mode13H that don't translate into modern computers well.

Comment: Mode13h - that brings back memories (swirling plasmas, flames and spinning cubes)! I would suggest you try the other book then, it will give you all the info you need.  With regards to lighting/shadows - you would have to do a huge amount of intersection tests to determine whether a surface should be lit or not.  Which brings me back to shadow mapping and shadow volumes - these techniques were invented to solve this exact problem, and to do it more efficiently than the technique you are trying :)